# Could not convert Tex math in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to write an algebraic equation in Rmarkdown but its rending as text as opposed to an algebraic equation. The warning below for reference;

> [WARNING] Could not convert TeX math 'Y_{ij}|b_{0i}=\large\beta_{0}+\large b_{0i}+\beta_{1}X_{ij}', rendering as TeX:

Comment: Try enclosing the equation in$ eg:  `$your_equation$` for an in-line equation or in double $$ as a block

Comment: I actually did that in the code;$$\large Y_{ij}|b_{0i}=\large\beta_{0}+\large b_{0i}+\beta_{1}X_{ij}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following code:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Author"
date: '2022-05-14'
output: word_document
---

$$
Y_{ij}|b_{0i}=\beta_{0}+b_{0i}+\beta_{1}X_{ij}
$$
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I would like it in word document.

Comment: @Magut, I updated my code. The error seems to happen when using `\large`.

Comment: Perfect!. It worked just as I wanted